# Weird for loop condition

Tags: c, visual-studio, for-loop

This for loop works even though the condition is given is as just `t`.

How is this possible when its not even a valid condition?
Are there many other exceptions like this ?

```
for (t=10; t; --t) {
  printf("%d",t);
}
```

Comment: `0 -> false`, `! 0 -> true` that is pretty much it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is this possible when its not even a valid condition. Are there many other exceptions like this ?

This is possible and valid condition.
The second sub-expression `t` in the for loop is to check whether `t` is equal to `0` or not. It is equivalent to

```
for (t=10; t != 0 ; --t) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

booleans in C are effectively integers. 0 is false and all non-zero values are true. As a result the second expression is 'true' while `t != 0`

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid condition as `t` exists and as a value. Simply put, a conditional expression just checks if the result is `!= 0` (evaluated to true) and is false otherwise.

When you use the conditional operators (`==`,`!=`, etc.) it actually returns a result that is 0 or 1, try it:

```
int a = 2;
printf("Result: %d, %d\n", a == 1, a == 2);
```